# Get 3d point(x,y,depth) coordinates from the image camera to another image camera

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I have two images of two stereo already calibrated and rectified. I made the stitching to build a panoramic image based on the two images, so I have the homography matrix, and I can also find the matrices R and T based on H. I use the function perspectivetransform to find the correspondence of a point 2d of the image 1 in the panoramic image.

Problem:

My stereos are positioned on top-view , if I look for the correspondence of a point of non-planar point (for example point of detection which corresponds to a head of person), I can not find its correspondence in the stitched image?

I have also the 3d points (x, y, depth) in the real coordinate that corresponds to my detection points, when I multiply this point by either the homography matrix or by R | T, I do not find the point of destination in picture 2 (I know his coordinates in 3d too).
did you have any solutions?